# Should I html encode values in an input field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss

Which should I use?

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" 
value="<%= person.first_name %>" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" 
value="<%= Html.Encode( person.first_name ) %>" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should Html.Encode else a " in the field could lead to injection problems

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a default value for an HTML element, you have to encode [the HTML special characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/charset.html#h-5.3.2) inside the value using [character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.3).

Comment: Gumbo can u please go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49378/room-for-royi-namir-and-gumbo) I have small question regarding this answer of yours

Comment: Hi. sorry . waited long time :-) can u please try again ? I'll wait.